# Why does SonarQube instance skip source folders named src-gen?

Tags: eclipse-plugin, sonarqube, tycho

We are using SonarQube for the analysis for Eclipse plug-ins with multiple source folders - one for manually written code and others for different kinds of generated code. Lately, we have noticed that not all source code was analyzed, although we have found no exclusion rule set up. A detailed analysis has shown, that all code from source folders named src-gen are ignored, and all other is present.

E.g. in case of the [project named org.eclipse.incquery.patternlanguage](http://git.eclipse.org/c/incquery/org.eclipse.incquery.git/tree/plugins/org.eclipse.incquery.patternlanguage), we have three source folders, *src*, *src-gen* and *xtend-gen*, but our build executing Sonar (and using Eclipse Tycho in the background) only reports in the source paths element the *src* and *xtend-gen* folders.

```
[INFO] -------------  Scan org.eclipse.incquery.patternlanguage
[INFO] Load module settings
[INFO] Base dir: /home/jenkins/workspace/EMF-IncQueryv2-NightlyAnalysis/core/plugins/org.eclipse.incquery.patternlanguage
[INFO] Working dir: /home/jenkins/workspace/EMF-IncQueryv2-NightlyAnalysis/core/plugins/org.eclipse.incquery.patternlanguage/target/sonar
[INFO] Source paths: pom.xml, src, xtend-gen
```

We have found similar cases in other projects as well: only the source folders named *src-gen* gets ignored, everything else analyses correctly. My question is how to tell SonarQube to analyze the *src-gen* folders as well?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We tend to think that generated code should not be analyzed. That's why in Eclipse we are excluding folders marked as 'derived'. You can still manually configure the analysis for this project by setting property sonar.sources = pom.xml,src,src-gen,xtend-gen in SonarQube / SonarLint project settings.

---

This discussion was continued on the SonarQube forum, and finally a [corresponding bug was found](https://jira.sonarsource.com/browse/MSONAR-134)

Comment: Adding the sonar.sources property indeed solved our issue. However, why is it that the Maven build ignores the src-gen, but not the xtend-gen folders? In case of the Maven builds, no derived setting from Eclipse is present, and src-gen folders are consistently ignored in all source folders.

Comment: In general, analysis of the generated code is less useful than analysis of the original source code/models. However, if there is no analysis tool available for the source model, analyzing the generated code can still be useful.

Comment: For Maven build it depends how you run your analysis. For example if you are using build helper plugin to add source folders you may have to run `mvn verify sonar:sonar` as a single reactor.

Comment: We are using Tycho that loads the source folders either from the .classpath or build.properties (I think, the latter, but I am not sure). However, all source folders are handled equally in the build (at least as far as I know), but only src-gen gets excluded, xtend-gen does not...

Comment: Please join SQ google group and provide a sample project to demonstrate the issue. Thanks

Comment: I have opened https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/sonarqube/kSTvjE0wW20 for future discussion.